# Existing htaccess only permitting Wget access but is actually blocking Wget/1.19.1 - Why?

Tags: .htaccess, unix, wget

I have previously setup htaccess file within a directory that ONLY permits access to files from Wget.  This is to stop casual webbrowsing of these folders but to still allow Wget from a remote system I have developed to downloaded updated files.

The current htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=Wget
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=302,L]
```

That's it - There nothing more to it - Any other browser gets redirected back to the main site.

This has been working fine.  BUT just recently, some of the system had a Wget upgrade and are now running versions which include 1.91.1 - I can see from my server logs that any remote box reporting it's user agent as Wget is able to download files, but any remote box reporting it's user agent as any other variation (such as Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnueabi) are being redirected back to the site index and actually end up downloading the site's main index file.

Do I need to add somekind of wildcard at the end of Wget wihtin my htaccess to allow any version of Wget?

Comment: Use string match expression with a pattern. Also, if you are in control of the clients and the server there's no reason not to have a real access control method.

Comment: I’m not in control of the client. And the site is public. How would I go about using a string match expression please? Any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: I seem to have been able to work this a slightly different way, but whilst I allows access to wget and variations, it blocks rathers than redirects other browsers.  Is it possible to do both (allow all variants of wget and redirect others) - Current htaccess file now looking like this. 

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*wget.* systems
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Wget.* systems

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=systems